# Falta de memoria en R

Tags: r

Esty corriendo un script para correlacionar raster, son capas de variables marinas para el mundo entero, por lo que son un poco pesadas en cuanto a información, la resolución del raster es 9 km en cada pixel, este es el script:

```
memory
rm(list = ls())

# packages
library(caret)
library(corrplot)
library(GGally)
library(landscapetools)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)

# directory
path <- "/home/mude/Downloads/Recortado actual"
setwd(path)
dir()

# import rasters -------------------------------------------------
# list variables
asc <- dir(pattern = ".asc$")
asc

# import
var <- raster::stack(asc)
var

# names
names(var) <- names(var) %>% stringr::str_replace("X", "var")
names(var)

landscapetools::show_landscape(var[[1]])

# extract values
var_da <- var %>% 
  raster::values() %>% 
  na.omit

# verify
head(var_da)
dim(var_da)

# correlation ----------------------------------------------------
# directory
dir.create("correlation")
setwd("correlation")

# correlation spearman
corr <- cor(var_da, method = "spearman")
corr

# export
readr::write_csv(tibble::as_tibble(corr), "correlation.csv")

# correlation plot
corrplot::corrplot(corr, type = "lower", diag = FALSE, tl.srt = 45, mar = c(3, 0.5, 2, 1))

# export figure
tiff("corr.tif", wi = 18, he = 18, units = "cm", res = 300, comp = "lzw+p")
corrplot::corrplot(corr, type = "lower", diag = FALSE, tl.srt = 45, mar = c(3, 0.5, 2, 1))
dev.off()

# select variables -------------------------------------------------------------
# verify
caret::findCorrelation(corr, cutoff = .7, names = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)

# correlated variables
fi <- caret::findCorrelation(corr, cutoff = .7)
fi

# new test
corr_fi <- cor(var_da[, -fi], method = "spearman")
corr_fi

# verify
caret::findCorrelation(corr_fi, cutoff = .7, names = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)

# export
readr::write_csv(tibble::as_tibble(corr_fi), "correlation_fi.csv")

# graphic
ggpairs(var_da[, -fi] %>% tibble::as_tibble() %>% dplyr::sample_n(1e3), 
        lower = list(continuous = wrap(ggally_points, pch = 21, color = "black", fill = "blue", size = 2, alpha = .7)),
        diag = list(continuous = wrap(ggally_barDiag, color = "gray10", bins = 15)),
        upper = list(continuous = wrap(ggally_cor, color = "black", size = 5, method = "spearman"))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(colour = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 8, colour = "black"), 
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 13),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 13), 
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white"))

# export
ggsave("correlation_plot.tiff", wi = 20, he = 15, un = "cm", dpi = 300, comp = "lzw+p")

# end
```

pero donde dice

```
landscapetools::show_landscape(var[[1]])

# extract values
var_da <- var %>% 
  raster::values() %>% 
  na.omit

# verify
head(var_da)
dim(var_da)
```

me pone el siguiente error: ERROR: cannot allocate vector of size 854.3 Mb
como puedo forzar a la maquina a hacerlo¿?`Necesito forzar a la maquina a correr el código, como puedo aumentar el uso de memoria de la maquina para el programa R corra el código?..Se puede correr este codigo en algun lugar en internet si mi maquina no me permitiera hacerlo?

Comment: Entiendo que estás corriendo esto sobre un linux, no? de 64 bits?

Comment: si asi es, ya se me ha reiniciaod varias veces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pareciera que el problema es este: `var_da <- raster::values(var)` (lo simplifico sin pipes), tienes un objeto `var` seguramente enorme, y haces algún tipo de transformación que genera otro objeto `var_da` también de un importante en tamaño. Lamentablemente, hasta el momento del error, tienes un "deficit" de 854Mb. **R**, y casi cualquier programa existente, maneja sus datos en memoria RAM, el tema es que, a diferencia de la mayoría de los programas, para las operaciones en la que se usa **R**, es habitual trabajar con grandes cantidades de datos. **R**, en la medida que el sistema operativo se lo permita, va a reclamar la mayor cantidad de memoria física disponible para lo que se necesite, por lo que cuando obtenemos un error como el tuyo, hemos llegado al límite y el SO no nos puede dar más.

#### ¿Existe alguna solución general?

Existen varias eventuales u no del todo seguras soluciones. Podemos explorar algunas de ellas.

- **Incrementar la memoria física**: La opción más segura, siempre que sea posible económica y técnicamente. En tu caso, 1 o 2 gbytes de RAM adicionales, solucionarían el problema (al menos hasta el momento del error, hay que ver si luego tu script requiere más ram)
- **Reducir el uso de memoria**. Estamos sobre un linux, entonces podrías probar **(a)** Cerrar todo programa corriendo innecesario **(b)** Deshabilitar todo servicio/demonio que no necesitemos en este momento **(c)** Como forma drástica, iniciar linux en modo texto, y ejecutar el script directamente con R (no Rstudio), para evitar la carga del servidor X que siempre es el que mas memoria se lleva (cuidado, muchas de las operaciones en R, aunque no se manifiesten de forma gráfica, requieren funcionalidad del servidor X). **(d)** No está de más quitar toda carga de librerías u objetos innecesarias en tu script.
- **Ejecutar tu script en otro equipo con más recursos**. Si tienes un colega que te puede prestar su equipo sería ideal. Puedes probar el servicio gratuito en la nube de [Rstudio](https://rstudio.cloud/), tenían planes de subir la cuota de ram de 1Gb a algo más, habría que probarlo. Otra alternativa es usar (con costo) algún proveedor de servicios en la nube tipo [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-aws/) (Microsoft, IBM y google entre otros, deben tener opciones parecidas), que te permitiría contratar la configuración deseada por un límite reducido de tiempo (el que necesites)
- **Reducir el tamaño de la muestra**. Hasta dónde entiendo, estas agrupando un conjunto de imágenes raster en layers en el objeto `var`, ¿Se puede reducir esta cantidad de layers? ¿Es posible interporlar esta imágenes para reducir la resolución?

#### ¿Y alguna solución particular?

Como ya dije, pareciera que el problema está aquí `var_da <- raster::values(var)`, `values()` genera una matriz enorme de enteros (cada columna es un layer), luego, según entiendo quitas aquellas filas dónde en algún `layer` tienes un  `NA` con  `na.omit`, si eventualmente se repitieran `NA` en la fila completa, una forma alternativa sería reemplazar esto:

```
var %>% 
  raster::values() %>% 
  na.omit
```

Por:

```
var_da <- na.omit(rasterToPoints(var )[,-c(1,2)])
```

Según la documentación de `rasterToPoints()`:

> Raster to point conversion. Cells with NA are not converted.

Y lo que nos retorna:

> A matrix with three columns: x, y, and v (value), or a SpatialPointsDataFrame object

**Importante**: el éxito de este método va a depender de cuantas filas tienen `NA` en todos los layers.